# Contact ListVew Working In Emulator But Not in Real Device

Tags: android

I have made an application in Android 2.2 that Displays only three things in `listview`. All Phone book, Contacts, and Number in `ListView` with `CheckBox`. When I Run The App in Emulator 2.2 then it is working properly, but when I use the real device to test an application then it will only display contacts Email ids and when `CheckBoxes` are used the app crashes.

I want clear that I don't call email ids from anywhere. I have used the code below to call fetch contact details from Phone book.

In BaseAdapter Class :

```
             ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
             cr = context.getContentResolver();
         cursor = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);


public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) 
{

                    if(cursor != null){
             while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                    int nameFiledColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(
                                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    String id = cursor.getString(
                            cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                         null, 
                         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                         new String[]{id}, null);   

                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                     phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

    }
```

Does anybody have any idea about what mistakes I have made ?

Comment: what error you are having in logcat.

Comment: i dont have aby error in LogCat in Emulator That app working nicely but in Device there is a problem........

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
     ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur
                    .getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (Integer
                    .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                // Query phone here. Covered next

                Cursor phoneCur = contentResolver.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                while (phoneCur.moveToNext()) {
                    // Do something with phones
                    String phoneNo = phoneCur.getString(pCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    contactDataset = new ContactDataset(); //This is object of dataset class to add the contacts.
                    contactDataset.setName(name);
                    contactDataset.setPhoneNumber(phoneNo);
                    getContactList.add(contactDataset);                     
                }
                pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Let me know is it works or not.......